# MissingSchemaError: schema hasn't been registered for model but sometime can get data

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, next.js13

I'm using Mongoose in Nextjs. I have three models: Actor, Producer, and Category. And one model called Film has all of these models in an array. And I'm using ref: 'Actor' (rest like this) for field actor. When I try to retrieve data from MongoDB and have it populate in a query, I have the error: MissingSchemaError: schema hasn't been registered for the model...
But sometimes I can retrieve data successfully. I don't know why or how. Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

Actor Model

```
  import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";
  const ActorSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  info: {
    type: String
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
  }
})

const Actor = models.Actor || model("Actor", ActorSchema)

export default Actor;
```

In Film model:

```
  actor: [{
     type: ObjectId,
     ref: 'Actor'
 }],
```

Query:

```
  films = await Film.findOne({slug: params.id}).populate(['actor','category','producer']).exec();
```

Comment: Could you please post your schemas and queries so we can see how you are referencing the other scheams and how you are doing the populate? Please post as code instead of images so that your issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @jQueeny yeah I updated. I'm just realize that with get by Id, this error don't exist, but with get by slug, it's show

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of time spent with this issue I have finally found the solution.

The NextJS page that is getting data from the server with getServerSideProps via database call needs to have the referenced model file imported like so:

```
import './your-path-to-your-module-with-the-actor-model'
```

This way by importing the file containing the referenced model at the top of your page file you are registering the Actor model before you use it down below inside getServerSideProps.